# convert string into url to send data to mysql objective c iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

I am trying to convert a string into url but not getting success. any better way to do, or improve the below code. thanks

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://domain.com/This Is My, Code for This. app";
NSString *escapedUrlString = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(escapedUrlString);
```

It is showing this log

> http://domain.com/This2s2y,芙ode
>   0.000000or2his.20x1.55e800047f4p-1029pp

Here is my actual code sending and save data to mysql

```
NSString *data = @"This Is My, Code for This. app";
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/connection.php?data=%@", data];   

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  

NSURL *urll = [NSURL URLWithString:strResult];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urll];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
```

No success with this, but when I use

```
data = @"ThisIsMyCode";
```

Then everything works fine...
Help

Comment: Where u have used this line in your code.

Comment: NSString *escapedUrlString = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: I use this code in viewdidload for checking the a string is replacing escape/space with %20 or not.. but it is not. If it does change then may be i use in my code

Comment: It shoud work, please paste correct url after encoding. I could not see it propery.

Comment: See answer 1' s commenys also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *data = @"This Is My, Code for This. app";
NSString *escapedDataString = [data stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/connection.php?data=%@", escapedDataString];
    NSLog(@"Encoded:%@",strURL);
```

This works fine, this is the log:

```
Encoded:http://domain.com/connection.php?data=This%20Is%20My,%20Code%20for%20This.%20app
```

Comment: Ok that person has not printed 'NSLog' properly.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",escapedUrl); anyways nice approach.